# Get the stream content file from remote files

Tags: php, xml, zip, sftp, phpseclib

I'm using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net) to connect to SFTP from PHP. 
I need to get a zip files from the SFTP Server. Those zip files contains xml and jpg files. I should extract data from xml and stream from jpg files and then save all in the database. I can't download the zip file because I haven't write permissions.

Can I get the stream content file (zip, xml and jpg) from remote files? Note that I'm using phpseclib.

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried? Why doesn't it work for you? Where is your code? Which error are you getting? Into which problem did you run? What have stopped you from doing that so far? Isn't it much easier to obtain write access? Can't you operate from a third system that has write access? Why is the database not accessible from a third server? Anything else I've forgotten to ask you? Please note that you are using some software that is specific like Phpseclib but you have not provided any specific information like server name, protocol versions, connection code and reference documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the stream content, however for the ZIP you need to program yourself a library that operates on the stream for the ZIP format (I do not know which one of the existing libraries can that out of the box, the ones I know can't, perhaps pclzip).

Then you need to operate on in-memory streams from the ZIP for the XML and JPG files which again needs to use stream compatible libraries - most likely you will need them to write yourself in context of PHP. Or at least invest a fair amount of time to deal this way.

But yes, it's perfectly possible. And (hopefully) you can do it.